# Clickable markers on image (one event listener on whole html collection) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems to make markers clickable in javascript. The markers are points on picture and their html class is marker. I want them all to be clickable and then test, whether the clicked marker had the id I wanted (I am able to test this).

This is the piece of code I am talking about:

```
function hladajEU(){
      var dlzkaPola = euRandomMesta.length;
      var klikanie = 0;
      var i=0;
      hladane = euRandomMesta.pop();
      var vsetkyMesta = document.getElementsByClassName("marker");
      console.log(vsetkyMesta);

         //document.getElementById('hladaneMesto').innerHTML= hladane.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          vsetkyMesta.onclick=function(){
              console.log("x");
          }   

  }
```

I want the whole list of markers to be clickable, but this is not working. Can anybody help me? I don´t want to use jQuery. I would like to add one listener to HTML collection. I would like to avoid solution, when I have to go through the collection like `vsektyMesta[i]`... if it is possible...

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a html collection, array like object, you need to access it as such: `vsetkyMesta[0]`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wanted to avoid this solution, but there is probably no other solution.

Comment: Avoid how? Like make only one event listener?

Comment: Yes, exactly, one listener on whole html collection. I think it is somehow possible when using jQuery.

Comment: No jQuery just does a loop of the html collection. But there is a single event solution I will add an answer to demonstrate. Also you should update your question to reflect that is what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Question was updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a seperate listener for each element you can use the fact that click events bubble up the dom tree. What that means is that you can set a single event on the parent element of your markers and then in the listener check to see if the target of the event is a marker or not, if so then do what you need to.

So if say the below was your html markup:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
   <div class="marker">1</div>
   <div class="marker">2</div>
   <div class="marker">3</div>
   <div class="marker">4</div>
</div>
```

Then all you would need to do is add an click listener on `container` and just check for marker

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click",function(e){
   //e.target will reference the element that triggered the event
   //classList.contains will return true if the element has a class
   //named marker
   if(e.target.classList.contains("marker")){
       console.log('x'); 
   }
});
```

[Event.target reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

[Element.classList reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Note that classList has support in most [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), you will have to use something else to check the class in those that do not.

For instance

```
e.target.className == "marker"
```

Demo

```js
var log = document.querySelector("#log");

document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click",function(e){
   if(e.target.classList.contains("marker")){
       log.innerText = "Clicked Marker: "+e.target.innerText; 
   }
});

Demo
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}

.marker {
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:#D22;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  z-index:10;
}

.marker:nth-child(1n){
  top: 20px; 
  left:35px;  
}
.marker:nth-child(2n){
  top: 50px; 
  left:100px;  
}
.marker:nth-child(3n){
  top: 0px; 
  right:0px;  
}
.marker:nth-child(4n){
  top: 100px; 
  left:30px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
   <div class="marker">1</div>
   <div class="marker">2</div>
   <div class="marker">3</div>
   <div class="marker">4</div>
</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vsetkyMesta` is an array of HTML elements(markers). You have to add the onclick handler on every marker in a loop block.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wanted to avoid this solution, but there is probably no other solution